# How can I use the programming language to find the vertices of a quadratic equation?

Tags: python, static

How can I use the programming language to find the vertices of a quadratic equation? For example, I have an equation like this.

```
Y=3X**2-12X+4
```

Although I can use the following way to find the minimum value of Y

```
x=np.arange(-100,101,1)
y=3*np.power(x,2)-12*x+4
print(np.min(y))
```

But then I don't know how to use the program to find the X value, I can only solve the problem using mathematical equations, so please help, thank you.

```
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import  numpy as np
x=np.arange(-100,101,1) 
y=3*np.power(x,2)-12*x+4
print(np.min(y))
'''
-8=3x**2-12x+4
-12=3x**2-12x
-12=3(x**2-4x)
-4=x**2-4x
0=x**2-4x+4
0=x**2-2*2x+2**2
0=(x-2)**2
'''
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use argmin ([link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html#numpy.argmin))

```
x[ y.argmin() ]
```